# toggle element, if first clicked toggle all element inside that div

Tags: jquery, toggle

Imagine each div as a card in your hand, and you have to choose which ones to play.

I can't change group class name nor element class name.

RULES:

- if an element clicked its toggle his position <-- left/right -->
- if the first element of the group clicked all element in that group goes right -->
- if all elements in that group are already on the right, and the first element clicked just first element goes left

my code works but just for one group, not for 2-3-4 groups...

```js
$('.carta:first').click(function() {
  if ($('.isOut').length < $('.carta').length) {
    $('.carta').addClass('isOut');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('isOut');
  }
})

$('.carta:not(:first)').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("isOut");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.carta {
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.isOut {
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=gruppo name=team[]>
  <div class="carta">1 first</div><br>
  <div class="carta">1</div><br>
  <div class="carta">1</div>
</div><br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class=gruppo name=team[]>
  <div class="carta">2 first</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
</div>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3mejdq4y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work for individual groups you need to change your selectors so they are relevant to the target `.gruppo`, not all `.carta` and `isOut` elements. To do that use `closest()` to get a reference to the parent element, then `find()` within it.

Also note that `:first` needs to be changed to `:first-child`, as you need to target the first element within each container, not the first overall.

Try this:

```js
$('.carta:first-child').click(function() {
  let $container = $(this).closest('.gruppo');
  if ($container.find('.isOut').length < $container.find('.carta').length) {
    $container.find('.carta').addClass('isOut');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('isOut');
  }
})

$('.carta:not(:first-child)').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("isOut");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.carta {
  background: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0%;
}

.isOut {
  margin-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gruppo" name="team[]">
  <div class="carta">1 first</div><br>
  <div class="carta">1</div><br>
  <div class="carta">1</div>
</div><br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="gruppo" name="team[]">
  <div class="carta">2 first</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
  <div class="carta">2</div><br>
</div>
```

Also note that the version of jQuery you're using, 1.11.0, is over 6 years old and should be updated.

Comment: you are my hero!

Comment: the first element in the second group "2 first" doesn't do his job (if clicked he don't toggle all element)

Comment: Ah, you're right. Change `:first` to `:first-child` to fix that